# Name of this plant

Tags: succulents

Saw this succulent at nursery quite liked it so i purchased it. Looks like sansevieria (Snake Plant) but dwarf there is also little pup coming from side

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is *Sansevieria*, the species might be *[Sansevieria trifasciata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sansevieria_trifasciata)* hahnii. However, hard to tell for sure. It is clear that your plant is not variegated, you often see *Sansevieria* with yellow bands, but yours doesn't have those. The plant is very easy to maintain, it doesn't need much water, and half shade is also fine.

Also known as mother-in-law's tongue.

Comment: Thanks @benn I also have the Sansevieria trifasciata with yellow edges growing beautiful every month

Comment: @OmiPenguin, yes me too, I have one with yellow stripes as well. Your plant in the picture might a Hahnii, a dwarf type. You'll have to wait and find out if it stays small.